# Differentiate $ e^{-[y/b]^a} $ respect to y?

Tags: derivatives

I would like to ask that,
when I do the differentiation $ \frac{\partial }{ \partial y} e^{-[y/b]^a}$,
my answer is $a \times e^{-[y/b]^a} \times (-1/b) $.
Is this correct? 
I am not sure whether $(-1/b)$ should be added.

Thank you very much for reading!!
Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite correct...
$$\frac\partial{\partial y}e^{-(y/b)^a}=e^{-(y/b)^a}×(-a\color{red}{(y/b)^{a-1}})×\frac1b$$

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out my mistake !!!! Appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac {d}{dy} e^{-(y/b)^a}=?$$

Let $$u=-(y/b)^a$$

Then $$\frac {du}{dy} = -a(y/b)^{a-1}(1/b)$$

Therefore your derivative is $$ \frac {d}{dy} e^{-(y/b)^a}=-a(y/b)^{a-1}(1/b)e^{-(y/b)^a}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindly help!!

Comment: Thanks for your attention and understanding.